# Simple Math - Calculate percentage from offseted range

Tags: math, range

Say you have scenario where you need to get percent value from range like 10-20. I.e. at 10 the value is 0.0 at 20 it is 1.0. I need this for a very simple algorithm. I can use clamping to get around this, but I was wondering if there is some nice and clean way to do this with simple math?

I can't change the start and end value, because they are indexes in For loop, so i need to get result of 0 all the time when index is 0-10 and from 10-20 it should be 0.0-1.0.

Answer (score 0):

For startrange <= value <= endrange the formula is:

```
double fraction = (value-startrange)/(endrange-startrange)
```

Otherwise fraction = 0 or 1, depending if value < startrange  or value > endrange

Answer (score 0):

It’s a simple linear interpolation problem between 10 and 20 like this (I assume you are using C-like language):

```
for (int i=0; i<=20; i++)
{
    if(i>=10 && i<=20)
    {
         Result = 0.1*(i-10);          
    }
    else
    {
        Result = 0.0;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.